# Make div scroll until it reaches top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the following example in wordpress - I need a div that holds an advert to start, say, 300px down the page, then scroll up witht he page until it reaches the top, then stay there if the user continues to scroll down. The example should explain this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jPxEY/

here it is in an html file that should work, everything seems there, but it will not work: http://www.altesc.net/exmp.html

In fact, if you look tot he right at the "Similar Questions" box and scroll down, it's exactly what i'm after.

I am pretty sure I've done everything correctly, but the javascript doesn't seem to work. If i copy everything from jquery and just add it directly to the header, and not in a separate js file, it works, it's only when i call jquery like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```

it fails to kick in.

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Added my header to help:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.altesc.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).scroll(function() {

var useFixedSidebar = $(document).scrollTop() > 330;
$('.adscrollleft').toggleClass('fixedSidebar', useFixedSidebar);

});

});//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: The example seems to work fine... What exactly is the problem?

Comment: At the very bottom of that file you're linking to is this: `jQuery.noConflict();` If you open Firefox's Firebug JS console or Chrome JS console, you'll see an error that `$` is not a function. To simplify for now, use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`, *especially* in the global scope. Other libraries use `$` the same way, which is why `jQuery.noConflict()` exists.

Comment: so as an example, $(window).load(function() should be jQuery(window).load(function()?

I've changed this, did not make it work. If someone could look at my html example on the first post and see if they can get it work, i can then look at the code for the fix.

Comment: It works on my computer. Here's the source for the one that works for me: http://pastebin.com/GCvaCF7c Note, too, that due to the size of the scroll, the browser cannot be maximized or the effect never occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment under the question, your jQuery include file has, *at the very very bottom*, a call to `jQuery.noConflict();`, which releases the `$` shorthand function reference to `jQuery()`.

So, the most straight-forward way to resolve this is to:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
        var useFixedSidebar = jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 330;
        jQuery('.adscrollleft').toggleClass('fixedSidebar', useFixedSidebar);
    });
});
```

And now your code works. Here's a Pastebin of the file that works on my computer (note you should not keep your browser maximized if you have a very large screen):

http://pastebin.com/GCvaCF7c

Some people really like the `$` shorthand, though, so you see this a lot:

```
//                   >>> The $ below <<<
jQuery(window).load(function($){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var useFixedSidebar = $(document).scrollTop() > 330;
        $('.adscrollleft').toggleClass('fixedSidebar', useFixedSidebar);
    });
});
```

jQuery allows you to use it in scope. Just get used to, now, using `jQUery()` anytime you're in the global scope at all.

Comment: thank you. I had a slight code error in the offline version i was using to test, only noticed it when you posted this. It now works. Thanks again.

Comment: I put a different way of the `$` in scope as well.

Comment: i suppose i have one final gripe. On being scrolled down the page, if i hit refresh, the js doesn't kick in until i scroll again - makes the box jump and look awkward. Does anyone know of anyway around this?

you can see what i mean by scrolling half way down on this page and seeing the add misalign: http://www.altesc.net/send-us-a-tip/

Comment: So you really [want a scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)? We spent so long waiting for `position: fixed` to get broadly supported, and what happens? Someone dreams up something even goofier. And to be honest, I'd encourage you to look for or ask another question, since that's not really what this one was about.

Comment: No. I found a way for it to refresh correctly, just had to use different js: http://pastebin.com/vdQgBujC

I guess the original way was basic and not ideal.

Comment: I appreciate that you took the initiative to find a fix; you might be surprised the number of people who don't even think to do that, and then people like me end up in the neverending question mode. You might leave a link in your question, too, in case it could help someone else. I think you got it from [this blog](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html), right?

Answer (score 1):

remove this: `$(window).load(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

- First, use a local copy of jQuery.

  Although the online copy would stay up all the time, it's best you have your own. To think of it in another way: What if the jQuery site went down? The script you are "leeching" would go down as well, and make your scripts that depend on the leeched jQuery to fail.
- Load libraries first

  Scripts are loaded and parsed in sequence, one after the other (unless some async stuff was used like `defer` or `async` attribute, or a dependency loader). If your snippet depended on jQuery and was loaded *before* jQuery, then it would fail. Load library scripts first, then the scripts that depend on it after.

  A quick Visual of what I mean:

  ```
  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
  <script src="yourScriptThatDependsOnJQuery.js"></script>
  <script>
      //scripts that depend on jQuery
  </script>
  ```

Comment: that was just an example, jquery is served locally.

The header is in sequence, maybe there are some errors?

 `<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryexample"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).scroll(function() {
    
    var useFixedSidebar = $(document).scrollTop() > 330;
    $('.adscrollleft').toggleClass('fixedSidebar', useFixedSidebar);
    
});

});//]]> 
</script>`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using CDN hosted includes. If you're itchy about it, use a loading fallback script or library, like Require.js. There's nothing wrong with hosting it yourself either, but the CDNs are pretty skilled at serving content.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

1. Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section
2. Be sure that you've included the dependant script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.
4. Watch out for jQuery caonflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.

Comment: Thing is, I've taken the example on jsfiddle and put it all into an html file with no extra scripts, just the bare example, yet it doesn't work:

Comment: @Jim - You have to *show us* what doesn't actually work. What sense does it make to say, hey, look, this works, but fix something else I'm not going to show you. ? Details.

Comment: if so if you follow above 4 steps correctly you must be good to go. if there are any errors post them here. let's see how can i help you

Comment: Sorry, was working on uploading the example, here it is http://www.altesc.net/exmp.html